# Office-js: If a single cell is selected, how can I lookup the last cell in the same column?

Tags: office-js

In Excel 2016 using Office.js, if the user selects a cell, how can I get the address of the last cell (with data in it) in the same column as the one the user selected?

```
 ________
|    A   |
----------
|        |
----------
|  Title |
----------
|   3    |    <----- user clicks here
----------
|   6    |  
----------
|   77   |    <----- how can I lookup this address?
----------
|        |
----------
|        |
----------
```

So I can have the array `[ [3], [6], [77] ]`.

Here's how I lookup the address of the cell the user selected:

```
Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
    let range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange().getUsedRange();
    range.load("address");
    await ctx.sync();
});
```

Which in this case should return an address of: **"Sheet1:A3"**
and I want to be able to get to: **"Sheet1:A3:A5".**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close; but what you need is to get the used range off of the entire column that contains the selection:

```
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        let range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        let usedRange = range.getEntireColumn().getUsedRange();
        usedRange.load("address");
        await context.sync();

        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(usedRange.address);
    })
```

You can try this snippet live in literally five clicks in the new Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following GIST URL: https://gist.github.com/Zlatkovsky/1393689cc63c002165e06fa6fb4eb755.  See [more info about importing snippets to Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I'll have to lookup OfficeHelpers, and, at a glance, Script Labs looks pretty nice. Definitely better than what I occasionally referenced before: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippet-explorer. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't affect how the code works, but you missed a semicolon on line 3. Or you can remove all the semicolons if you want to (e.g. [Standard](https://github.com/feross/standard))

Comment: Fixed semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @MichaelZlatkovsky's answer, this may also be useful:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/range.md#getlastcell

Docs - getLastCell():

```
Gets the last cell within the range. For example, the last cell of "B2:D5" is "D5".
```

So something like:

```
var range = range.getEntireColumn().getUsedRange().getLastCell();
```